Reading a binary file with Julia
Hi im new in Julia and im trying to do some proprocessing with it. I have a lot of files in binary. Im using F90 for the processing. The file that i write are like this
open(11,file="ring.grid",form="unformatted")

write(11)nv
write(11)Nx,Ny,Nzt
write(11) xx
write(11) yy
write(11) zz
close(11)



where, nv,nx,ny,nzt are integers and xx,yy,zz are 3D matrix. In F90 i use this simple block to read the file
open(11,file='ring.grid',form='unformatted')
read(11)nd
read(11)n1,n2,n3
read(11)xx
read(11)yy
read(11)zz
close(11)

But i have troubles to read it with Julia. Someone can help me with this?
Thank you
I tried using
io=read(NAMEFILE)
y=Array{UInt8,1}(undef,1)
read!(io,y)

But i dont know how i can separe the nv,n1,n2,n3,xx,yy,zz in differente arrays

Fortran sequential access binary files have special format that may not be recognized by other langaluages. Opening the file and writing with stream access may help resolve the error. Search for "fortran programming stream IO".

It  might be simplest to call some Fortran from Julia if you need to read standard Fortran unformatted files

Or you might look at FortranFiles.jl https://traktofon.github.io/FortranFiles.jl/stable/

Or more generally, if you want to do data interchange, use a data interchange file format.

Suppose that the complete F90 code to write the data looks like this:
program SaveGrid
    implicit none

    integer :: nv
    integer :: Nx, Ny, Nzt
    real, dimension(:), allocatable :: xx, yy, zz
    integer :: i

    nv = 3
    Nx = 5
    Ny = 7
    Nzt = 10

    allocate(xx(Nx), yy(Ny), zz(Nzt))

    do i = 1, Nx
        xx(i) = float(i)
    end do
    do i = 1, Ny
        yy(i) = float(i) * 2.0
    end do
    do i = 1, Nzt
        zz(i) = float(i) * 3.0
    end do

    open(unit=11, file="ring.grid", form="unformatted")

    write(11) nv
    write(11) Nx, Ny, Nzt
    write(11) xx
    write(11) yy
    write(11) zz

    close(11)

    deallocate(xx, yy, zz)
end program SaveGrid

To read this into Julia you need to handle the way that F90 writes unformatted data.
function read_fortran_binary(filename)
    open(filename, "r") do file
        # Read record marker.
        record_size = read(file, Int32)
        # Read data.
        nv = read(file, Int32)
        # Read record marker.
        end_record_size = read(file, Int32)

        # Read record marker.
        read(file, Int32)
        # Read data.
        Nx = read(file, Int32)
        Ny = read(file, Int32)
        Nzt = read(file, Int32)
        # Read record marker.
        read(file, Int32)

        return nv, Nx, Ny, Nzt
    end
end

nv, Nx, Ny, Nzt = read_fortran_binary("ring.grid")

println("nv:  ", nv)
println("Nx:  ", Nx)
println("Ny:  ", Ny)
println("Nzt: ", Nzt)

There are record markers both before and after each chunk of data written to the file. You need to read these too. Obviously you don't need to ignore these data and the record sizes can be used to make your Julia code more robust and flexible by catering for changes in the unformatted F90 data.
nv:  3
Nx:  5
Ny:  7
Nzt: 10


You are making assumptions about the format of the Fortran unformatted file - there is no guarantee the format is as you have it above, the Fortran standard says nothing about how it should be implemented. Different compilers can differ, and it has been known to differ between different versions of the same compiler. This is why I think calling Fortran to do the reading is probably the best way to go.

I concur with @IanBush statement. Binary files that are supposed to be read in other languages should be with written with the access="stream" modifier, which suppresses the record markers.

There are also modifications for records > 2 GB.

WRT access="stream" I think it would be useful if the OP clarified their use case - is it lots of existing files than can not easily be regenerated that need to be read, or are the files easily rewritten or regenerated in a different format?
